# Submatrix and element alignment within matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays

I'm having trouble aligning submatrices and elements within the same matrix. Essentially, what I want to do is this (excuse the terrible paint-job):

[image: example]

Where the submatrix Q is located at the middle of the upper-left four matrix cells. I'm primarily familiar with the array environment: is this a possibility there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about a matrix inside a matrix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{vmatrix}
    Q & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \\
    \begin{matrix} 2 & 3 \end{matrix} & -1
\end{vmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left|
\begin{array}{cr}
    Q & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \\
    \begin{matrix} 2 & 3 \end{matrix} & -1
\end{array}
\right|\]
\end{document}
```

using the `array` environment that allows a better alignment.

[image]

or maybe something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % for cropping
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
  \[ \left|
    \begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}r}
    \mbox{\LARGE $Q$} & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \\ \hdashline[2pt/2pt]
    \begin{matrix} 2 & 3 \end{matrix} & -1
    \end{array}
    \right|
  \]
\end{document}
```

that modifies the size of `Q` and includes dashed lines between columns using the `arydshln` package.

[image]

Comment: `amsmath` doesn't load the `array` package, and the `array` as well as the `matrix` environment are defined in plain LaTeX so need for `amsmath` in your example.

Comment: @Henri is correct, excuse me, but if i delete (or comment) the `amsmath` package i get an error (about `matrix`?). i already fixed my answer.

Comment: You're right. Seems like the standard `matrix` doesn't like to be nested, hence you will still have to use the `amsmath` package.

Comment: in cases like this, the "sub"element (here "Q") is often set in a larger size.

Comment: @barbarabeeton maybe you want to see something like that? (view my last edition)

Comment: @skpblack -- i think it may be one size larger than necessary, but yes, that's definitely what i had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

A third solution with `\multicolumn` and `multirow`. I defined a `\block` macro with two arguments: the number of rows and columns that the block takes up (expressed as a pair) and what it puts in the block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\block(#1,#2)#3{\multicolumn{#2}{c}{\multirow{#1}{*}{$ #3 $}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
\block(2,2){Q} & 0 \\
     & & 0 \\
     2 & 3 & \mathllap{-}1
\end{vmatrix*} \]

\[ \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
2 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \block(2,2){P} & 0 \\
  4 & & & 0 \\
3 &2 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix*} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Sorry, I mixed up with my clipboard manager. Fix this at once.

Answer (score 2):

With `{vNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}
\Block{2-2}<\Large>{Q} &   & 0 \\
                       &   & 0 \\
                     2 & 3 & -1 
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]